# Is it possible to create aliases that affect services starting?

Tags: shell, java, alias, services, profile

Currently I have a custom service that executes java in multiple places.

I want to be able to add an option to any executions of java this service will spawn (I'm specifying the error log location, which otherwise logs to the "working directory", which when services are started is "/"). It's also best if this option remains past initial service start.

I have doubts that placing:

```
alias java="java -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/java/java_error%p.log"
```

within `/etc/profile` will cut it, seeing as it is sourced for shell logins, and services are started before a login can even occur.

I'd rather not have to place this alias within the service's init script if I can avoid it. Is there an effective way to alias this so that it will affect service startup?

Comment: It's unlikely that your service starts a shell before being run. You'd better alter your service init script.

Comment: I agree with apaul. What's more, you don't want to abstract your service start ups. It should be setup that another admin could look at it and see how it is working. It is better to keep everything like this in the init script when possible. If you are running tomcat or similiar, you can place some settings in the server.xml.

Comment: I have realized there is a /etc/java/java.conf, and in this file is a variable that you can set that appends options to java executions. I will try to find some documentation on it and specify my log location in here.